# Hosting a Azure Service on a Local Machine for testing

Tags: web-hosting, azure

I am developing a `Azure` based cloud application. I have two machine, lets name them as `M1` and `M2`. On `M1`, I am running my azure service using `Azure Storage Emulator`, which by default runs on `port 81`, so on `M1` itself, I can access it by using `127.0.0.1:81`. Now I want to access it on `M2`. What additional things I have to setup to achieve this behavior? Both `M1` and `M2` are in same LAN and have `Windows 8` installed on them.

Comment: Should this not be as simple as accessing the ip address of M2:81?

Comment: No, I have already tried this but its not working for me. In Google Chrome, it says, Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to...

Comment: Is the firewall off on the host machine?